# Combine data from Kotlin Flow/LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm, kotlin-flow

I've got a flow from my repository that looks something like this:

```
val userListFlow: Flow<List<User>> = channelFlow<List<User>> {
        source.setOnUserUpdatedListener { userList ->
           trySend(userList)
        }
        awaitClose {
            logger.info("waitClose")
            source.setOnUserUpdatedListener(null)
        }
    }.stateIn(
       scope = externalScope,
       started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
       initialValue = emptyList()
   )


 suspend fun getUserThumbnail(user: User): File {
    return getUserThumbFromCache(user) ?: run {
       fetchUserThumbnailRemote()
    }
 } 

 private suspend fetchUserThumbnailRemote(user: User): Bitmap {
    thumbnailService.getUserThumbnailBitmap(user.id)
 }

 fun getUserThumbFromCache(user: User) {
    val thumbFile = getThumbFile(user)
    return if (thumbFile.exists() && thumbFile.size() > 0) {
      thumbFile
    } else null
 }

 private fun getThumbFile(user: User): File {
   return File(cacheDir, "${user.id}.jpg")
 }
}
```

For each of these users I can call the suspend function to get a thumbnail for the user.
I don't want to wait for the thumbnail before showing the list of users though, I'd rather it show the users and then when the thumbnail is fetched, update the list.

However I'd like the list to be updated when a thumbnail is fetched..

From my ViewModel I have something like

```
  data class UserWithThumb(user: User, thumb: File?)


  val userLiveData = repo.userListFlow.map {
      UserWithThumb(it, repo.getUserThumbFromCache(it))
  }.asLiveData()
```

So then from my Fragment I do

```
 viewModel.userLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
       userListAdapter.submitList(it)
 }
```

My thumbnails are all null though as I need to fetch them from remote. However if I call that function then that will delay my list from getting to the UI until the thumbnail is fetched. How can I get the thumbnail to the UI in a clean way? I realize that I need to have my livedata or flow update itself once the thumbnail is fetched but I have no idea how to hook that into my code. Any ideas would be appreciated.

I suppose one way to think about this is I'd like my upstream (repository) flow to contain the list of users but then I'd like to update the list given to the view not just when the upstream  (repo) flow gets new data but when new thumbnails are downloaded as well..

Comment: IMHO thumbnails are best requested by UI, as items get scrolled into view. So that'd be a different repo.

Comment: So if I request the thumbnail separately from a list view, how do I ensure it's being shown for the correct view?

Comment: I guess, if you monitor what enters viewport at recyclerview level, then it can launch a request for that item, and eventually fire `Adapter.notifyItemChanged` to refresh that one element. It's just a loose thought, yours and mine architectures seem to be vastly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from the question is, you have a list of `UserWithThumb` that is created once you set `User`s list and you want to show it to the UI immediately. In the background you want to fetch User thumbnails and once you receive them, you want to update the list again.

One way to achieve what you want is:

```kotlin
val userLiveData = flow {
    repo.userListFlow.collect { users ->
        val initialList = users.map { UserWithThumb(it, repo. getUserThumbFromCache(it)) }
        emit(initialList)
        coroutineScope {
            val finalList = users.map {
                async(Dispatchers.IO) {  // fetch all thumbnails in parallel
                    UserWithThumb(it, repo. getUserThumbnail(it))
                }
            }.awaitAll() // wait until all thumbnails have been fetched
            emit(finalList)
        } 
    }
}.asLiveData()
```

Comment: Nice! I would actually not want to wait for all thumbnails to be loaded though for the list to get updated. In reality these thumbnails aren't actually going over a network but a BLE connection that is very slow and can't be retrieved in parallel so partial updates are preferable. I actually did figure out how to do this similar to the above but it required that the code re-emit the entire list on each download. The code is a bit uglier but it did work.

Comment: So is your problem solved or are you looking for solution which updates the list on every thumbnail fetch?

Comment: I'd be interested in how you would do it.

Comment: `but it required that the code re-emit the entire list on each download`. There is no way other than re-emitting the entire list again. If you want the UI want the update, a new list has to be emitted.